# Unable to call method in Adapter(onBindViewHolder) from ViewHolder (RecycleView)

Tags: java, android

I worked on same project in previous Android Studio but now In this newer version am unable to code on the same Project!
I wrote `setData` method in `Viewholder(Adapter)` and when am trying to call this method in `onBindViewHolder{ .. }` It is not recognizing this method. (HAVE A LOOK AT UPLOADED IMAGE)
When I press <kbd>Atl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> it shows "rename reference".

Error throwing line - 34
Gist : https://gist.github.com/Reevan799/0babda6746136105f3c4fbdab1c12ae5#file-categoryadapter-java-L34

[Error Am Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49uGj.png)
Image URL : https://ibb.co/Kq3rg3G

Code :

```
   package com.example.generalknowledgequiz;

   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

   import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

   import java.util.List;

   import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

   public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

       private List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList;

       public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
           this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item,parent,false);
           return new Viewholder(view);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           holder.setData(categoryModelList.get(position).getImageurl(),categoryModelList.get(position).getTitle());  #Error Causing Line..
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return categoryModelList.size();
       }

       class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

           private CircleImageView imageView;
           private TextView title;

           public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
               super(itemView);
               imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

           private void setData(String url, String title){

               Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
               this.title.setText(title);
           }
       }
   }
```

`setData` is shown in Red color in Android Studio (`onBindViewHolder`)

Comment: Basically your setData method is private. Make it public it will work

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala, that is not the problem. `onBindViewHolder` accepts view holder of type `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and not the custom class `Viewholder` defined at the end of the class. It has nothing to do with private access modifier. Because this is a nested class all it's private members are also accessible to the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change generic type you used for `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Your class declaration should be:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.Viewholder> {
...
}
```

It will also require you to change the overridden methods declaration.

1. return type changed to `Viewholder`:

   ```
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item,parent,false);
      return new Viewholder(view);
   }
   ```
2. Argument type changed to `Viewholder`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position) {
       holder.setData(categoryModelList.get(position).getImageurl(),categoryModelList.get(position).getTitle());  #Error Causing Line..
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, You saved my time.